# jQuery DataTables - How can I globally filter data already filtered on a single column?

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

I'm using the jQuery [DataTables](http://datatables.net) plugin to display data being returned from an AJAX call. Once the data is returned, users can filter the rows on a single column (`"Status"` in this case).

What I would like to do is also use the global filter function. If the user has already filtered the data by a status of `"Pending"`, I want to have the global filter only return the rows where any row contains the text entered by the user and has a `Status = "Pending"`. How can I accomplish this?

I'm fairly new to jQuery so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: dont know if i understand u well, but u want  to filter inside a filter result ? Result, `Pending` , and then, filter anything with this result.

Comment: @Ricardo Basically yes. Let's say There are 100 total records and 15 with a status of `Pending`. When the user types in "123" in the search textbox I want to search those 15 records for the text "123".

Comment: Datatebles have this options: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html , now you will be able to choose the "result" and filter inside this result, check the link , you will see what i'm trying to say. see if helps you

Comment: you can use the combobox to choose what you want to show in the grid, then you work with this results..

Comment: @Ricardo That link you provided led me to the answer I needed. If you write it up as an official answer I'll upvote and mark it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as comments:

using this options from [datatable](http://datatables.net/) himself, can help you:

**[Multi_filter_select](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)**